# Google cloud Linux instance changes rolled back after reboot

Tags: google-compute-engine, centos7

I created a new Google cloud instance using their centos7 image.  Made some changes - such as enabling ntp like this:

```
# ntpq -p
ntpq: read: Connection refused
#systemctl enable ntpd
#systemctl restart ntpd
# ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*metadata.google 71.79.79.71      2 u    -   64    1    0.452    0.059   0.090
```

After stopping and the next day starting the instance, the changes were gone.  Can someone point me to how to persist changes or where it is they rollback changes?

Comment: I think this may be due to chronyd.

Answer (score 0):

GCE instances are preconfigured to use NTP. Refer to [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/managing-instances#configure-ntp) for more information on setting up NTP for the GCE instances.

To add, GCE instances are configured to [renew DHCP leases](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#internal_dns_and_resolvconf) every 24 hours and in CentOS ntp.sh script is located at: '/etc/dhcp/dhclient.d/'. The ntp script runs as well during DHCP renewal and commit changes as per the configuration file.

Comment: Navi - appreciate the feedback.  The link you included is what I reviewed before making any changes.  In fact the meta ntp server was already in the config, but ntp was not enabled and running and my initial ntpq query shows.  DHCP would only apply if they were not static ips already and I believe is separate from ntp (other than ntp would use that interface to communicate).  None of this explains why the enabling of ntp was undone by the reboot or some other process on the host.  So my question still stands

Comment: @user10262242 Strange, I tested the same using the Centos 7 image 'centos-7-v20180611' followed the steps you took and still I am able to see service running.  

sudo ntpq -p
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*metadata.google 71.79.79.71      2 u  182 1024  377    0.529    0.006   0.054

Can you test and verify again and provide the Centos image you are using, so I can test on my end as well?

Comment: did you reboot the instance?

Comment: As I mentioned above - this is due to chronyd.

Comment: @user10262242  Could you please update us about the version of CentOS you are using and more details about the image ? Furthermore, could you try it once when using only ntpd and once using only chronyd ? These document [1](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/centos-rhel-7-enable-ntp-to-start-at-boot-after-fresh-install-disable-chrony/) and [2](https://my.vertica.com/docs/8.1.x/HTML/index.htm#Authoring/InstallationGuide/BeforeYouInstall/chrony.htm) might be helpful for enabling and disabling such services.

Comment: I used the CentOS 7 image from google.  It was due to chronyd taking over for ntp... be sure to reboot the instance to see the behavior.